# All years between 2 years excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hi,

I am already searching the whole day for a formula (or VBA most likely) that can write down all the years between 2 years. So i have Column A:

- 1990
- 1994
- 1995
- 1992

Column B:

- 1995
- 2016
- 2001
- 1998

In Column C i want to get this:

1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995

Comment: So what have your searches / attempts been so far? I'm frankly surprised as if you just want to do this via VBA, it's a simple loop which you could likely find a tutorial for very quickly.

Comment: I hope you can find it then for me? Because i only found something that can get the years between but put the answers in multiple cells and not like i want in column C

Comment: I want A1 and B1 answer in C1 and go on.

Answer (score 1):

A formula like this in C1 dragged across would work, but you'd need to know the max difference and drag accordingly the  columns needed

`$A1+(IF(COLUMN()-2<=($B1-$A1),COLUMN()-2,0))`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need to say i am very new to formulas and i have Excel 2010. When i put it like this in Column C: =$A$1+(IF(COLUMN()-2<($B$1-$A$1),COLUMN()-2,0)) nothing happens

Comment: if you drag this across to column F, you get `1991, 1992, 1993, 1994` so long as your A1 and B1 are integers

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/56r33c/all_years_between_2_years_excel/

```
Sub concatYears()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, begYr As Long, endYr As Long, yrs As Long, yrStr As String

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow '<-- assuming data starts from row 2
    begYr = Cells(i, 1).Value
    endYr = Cells(i, 2).Value

    yrStr = ""

    For yrs = begYr To endYr - 1
        yrStr = yrStr & Str(yrs) & ", "
    Next yrs

    yrStr = yrStr & Str(endYr)
    Cells(i, 3).Value = yrStr
Next i

End Sub
```